# Keep database taken content on a page when entering the url in different browser/tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, web

I have a website in which i take some content (specified in a form) from a database with php, then json_encode it  to javascript code and then place it on the page. Whether i save this content in php session or not when i enter the page url from another tab or browser it doesnt show the content. I think that this is because i dont go through the form and the javascript is executed on the client(aka the variable in which i save the content is empty). My question is how can i show the content with just entering the url of the page, not going through the form. I suppose i should save the content on the server, but how?

Here's the code of the page with the form:
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/2356. 
 Here's the code of the page on which i show the content:
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/2355

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: If it's another browser, that makes sense because cookies (sessions) don't carry over -- unless you keep track of users via IP, which is a very bad idea because IPs change and that would mean everyone in LAN would have access.

Comment: You won't be able to get much help without the code.